# Comparing .Net Version instance using CompareTo does not work as expected

Tags: .net, version, compare, compareto

The Version class in .Net does not implement the CompareTo interface as I would expect, it seems to handle the compare alphanumerically instead of comparing the four numbers. Maybe not a bug, but a 'feature'.

Can anyone shine a light on why the compare (and also the standard <, = and > operators) do not work as I would expect below?

```
    Dim MainVersion As New Version("1.1.3251.4029")
    Dim Ver_Low As New Version("1.1")
    Dim Ver_Same As New Version("1.1.3251.4029")
    Dim Ver_High As New Version("1.1.5.0")

    ' CompareTo here yields 1 which is expected as MainVersion is greater than Ver_Low.
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}.CompareTo({1}) = {2}", MainVersion.ToString(), Ver_Low.ToString(), MainVersion.CompareTo(Ver_Low).ToString()))

    ' CompareTo here yields 0 which is expected as MainVersion and Ver_Same are the same.
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}.CompareTo({1}) = {2}", MainVersion.ToString(), Ver_Same.ToString(), MainVersion.CompareTo(Ver_Same).ToString()))

    ' **** Issue here **** CompareTo here yields 1 which is NOT expected as MainVersion is less than Ver_High.
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}.CompareTo({1}) = {2}", MainVersion.ToString(), Ver_High.ToString(), MainVersion.CompareTo(Ver_High).ToString()))
```

I know people have done their own manual workarounds for this, I'd like to know if this is by design or it should work and I might be doing something dumb.

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Update: I was doing something subtly dumb and treating them in the same was as IP addresses. For example; 1.1.3023.5364 is greater than 1.1.5 but 1.1.3023.5364 is < than 1.1.5000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's comparing the four parts, treating each as a number.
Which is the bigger number: 5 or 3251? Surely it's 3251.
Therefore version 1.1.3251.* is "newer" (i.e. greater) than 1.1.5.*.

If you've got 1.1.3251 coming before 1.1.5, then you're effectively using a single number (the "build" part) as a sequence of digits. That's a mistake.

Comment: I just checked using Reflector and I agree that is what it is doing, it does take some getting your head round it when you are used to thinking in terms of IP addresses with each quad being multipled.

Anyway, thanks for your clarification.